# Convert latitude/longitude fields into Geospatial Points

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial

I have a table with with a latitude, longitude and coordinates column. There are over 500,000 rows. The coordinates field is currently empty on every row. What I need to do is convert the latitude and longitude into a Geospatial POINT() and put it in the coordinates column. Is this possible?

I know that `POINT`s can be inserted like this:

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`coordinates`) VALUES (GeomFromText('POINT(50.2 51.6)'));
```

I essentially need to do exactly this but by pulling the value from `latitude` and `longitude` from each row.

Comment: Is the latitude 50.2, and the longitude 51.6?

Comment: @ganders No that's just an example. There are 500,000 different latitude and longitude points as FLOAT(10,6) type

Comment: What I'm asking is, does the 50.2 map to the latitude column, and the 51.6 maps to the longitude column? (and there are 500,000 entries, like you said)

Comment: @ganders Yes that's correct (sorry), latitude - longitude

Comment: What version of Mysql are you using?

Comment: @Ray MySQL version 5.6.14

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A GeomFromText needs a string, you've got to lot of concatenate

```
INSERT INTO myTable (coordinates)  
   SELECT GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',ot.latitude, ' ', ot.longitude,')'))
    FROM otherTable ot;
```

If it's an update to an existing table with `latitude` and `longitude` columns into a new column `coordinates` do this:

```
UPDATE  myTable 
 SET coordinates =  GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',latitude, ' ', longitude,')'));
```

Comment: Would it not be better to use a 'UPDATE' if all the columns are in the same table?

Comment: @jskidd3 If the lat& long are in the same table, yes, do an update.  I wasn't sure they were.

Comment: Apologies my fault, could you update your SQL to represent this?

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'longitude,')'))' at line 2" (for the update query)

Comment: @jskidd3 I'm testing this on the following table structure and I don't get the sql error you're seeing: CREATE TABLE `myTable2` (
  `latitude` float unsigned NOT NULL,
  `longitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `coordinates` geometry DEFAULT NULL
)

Comment: @jskidd3 maybe the whitespace?

Comment: @jskidd3 both the insert and update seem to run on my 5.5 system with the table I included.  Can you post your create statement to the question?

Comment: Alls good thanks Ray, working perfectly. Cheers for your help

Answer (score 7):

This is a older question but I have remarked that all answers are wrong (at least in 2019) latitude and longitude must be opposite as the answers

instead: `POINT(latitude,longitude)`

**Must be:** `POINT(longitude,latitude)`

In Mysql 5.6 and later can use :

```
Update myTable
Set coordinates = POINT(longitude, latitude);
```

If we try some like:

```
SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(
    POINT(13.1500000,99.9666700), 
    POINT(48.861105, 120.335337)
);
```

got error:

> ERROR 1210 (HY000): Incorrect arguments to st_distance_sphere

Because I have used like in the answers `POINT(latitude,longitude)`

But if we try `POINT(longitude,latitude)`:

```
SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(
    POINT(99.9666700, 13.1500000), 
    POINT(120.335337, 48.861105)
);
```

The result is:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| ST_Distance_Sphere(
        POINT(99.9666700, 13.1500000),
        POINT(120.335337, 48.861105)
    ) |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                      4389299.754585881 |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
Update myTable
Set coordinates = GeomFromText('POINT(' + latitude + ' ' + longitude + ')')
```

This is assuming your coordinates column exists in the same table as your lat and long.

(Keep in mind this is SqlServer/Tsql syntax)...