# how to set GEOMETRY in MySQL from coordinates of JSON_ARRAY

Tags: mysql, database, geography

I want to update my dataset and use the GEOMETRY datatype instead of using latitude and longitude. The problem is I have set a geo column in my table with the datatype yet I can't put my data in it. how to set its value?

I searched through other questions and all of them use text and I wanted to transform from JSON.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert latitude/longitude fields into Geospatial Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188765/convert-latitude-longitude-fields-into-geospatial-points)

Comment: All answers use text, yet I would like to transform to geo from JSON, so not as useful as it could be.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your existing data.

Comment: my sample data is `[1,2]` as `JSON_ARRAY` and for this to be used I found `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(JSON_OBJECT('type', 'Point', 'coordinates', JSON_ARRAY(5, 10)))`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To update the field, we need to follow this format
first we create a JSON that has type and coordinates and then transform it to GEO. Also, note that coordinates are in the format of JSON array.

here is an example for type `Point` and coorinates of `(5, 1)`

`ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(JSON_OBJECT('type', 'Point', 'coordinates', JSON_ARRAY(5, 10)))`

Answer (score 1):

If your table currently has a JSON column containing the latitude and longitude you could use something like this:

**tbl**

| id | json_point | new_point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"latitude": "51.5072", "longitude": "0.1276"} |  |

```sql
UPDATE tbl SET new_point = POINT(json_point->>'$.longitude', json_point->>'$.latitude');
```

If json_point contains a JSON array:

| id | json_point | new_point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [0.1276, 51.5072] |  |

you could update with:

```sql
UPDATE tbl SET new_point = POINT(json_point->'$[0]', json_point->'$[1]');
```

Comment: Thank you, I had `JSON_ARRAY` as input, and this also was quite helpful `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(JSON_OBJECT('type', 'Point', 'coordinates', JSON_ARRAY(5, 10)))`

Comment: Thank you, I also updated the question so that I would be more precise.